# ARM Templates ignoring "=" in body or parameter

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

As part of a Appfabric Mesh deployment i need to pass a Base64 encoded symmetric encryption key in command like below:

```
az mesh deployment create --resource-group MeshRG --template-file dep.json --parameters  aeskey='YmFzZTY0IGRlY29kZXI='
```

The issue is that the trailing '=' (padding char) is always being ignored by ARM and it would read only `YmFzZTY0IGRlY29kZXI` in above case.

I have tried double quotes, separate json parameter file and even tried to put it in the ARM template file it self. In all cases it it ignores the trailing =

Comment: can you present a repro? this seems a bit hard to believe

Comment: looks like it is an open issue with service fabric mesh:  https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-mesh-preview/issues/264 https://github.com/amolenk/AirportMesh/issues/1